# Confused by the generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

In the code below (taken from Javascript Concurrency), there should be three generator objects after the `iterable = genMap(iterable, iteratee)` for-of loop. However, `yield* iterable` is a single reference. How does it `yield` three sets of values from `genMap`? Thank you.

```
function* genMap(iterable, iteratee) {
    for (let item of iterable) {
        console.log('item', item)
        yield iteratee(item);
    }
}

function composeGenMap(...iteratees) {

    return function* (iterable) {
        for (let iteratee of iteratees) {
            iterable = genMap(iterable, iteratee);
        }

        yield* iterable; 
    }
}

// Our iterable data source.
var array = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

var composed = composeGenMap(
    x => x + 1,
    x => x * x,
    x => x - 2
);

for (let item of composed(array)) {
    console.log('composed', item)
}
// →
// composed 2
// composed 7
// composed 14
```

Comment: `yield*` defers execution to another generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield*` defers execution to another generator, or perhaps an iterable if you so desire.

That means it can technically `yield` more than one value (three in your case).

From [the Mozilla Developer Network article on `yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*):

> The yield* expression is used to delegate to another generator or iterable object.

Comment: I see ... however that only seems to explain a single index from the array passed to composed(array). For instance, the first value of array is 2 and it is transformed three times:  // 1 => 1 + 1 = 2, 2 => 2 * 2, 4 => 4 - 2 = 2. I still don't understand why the single "iterable" isn't mutated ....?

Comment: This example might clarify things for you about order of execution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield%2A#Delegating_to_another_generator

Comment: @bresson Did that example help at all?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you gyre.